# Django Model Forms AttributeError while setting instance value

Tags: python, django

I want to set profile's avatar, but I get an error while updating object:
**'Profile' object has no attribute 'profile'**

I've created a model:

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
   slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True)
   avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar, null=True, blank=True)
```

And Model Form:

`froms.py`

```
from PIL import Image

class AvatarForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar',]

    def save(self):
        avatar = super(AvatarForm, self).save()
        im = Image.open(avatar.avatar)
        resized_image = im.thumbnail(64, 64)
        resized_image.save(avatar.avatar.path)

        return avatar
```

Template rendering as usual:

`template.html`

```
<form action="{% url 'avatar_add' me.slug %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field avatar_form.avatar class="form-control form-control-sm" accept="image/*" onchange="this.form.submit()"%}
</form>
```

And url reciever:

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/avatar_add$', AddAvatar, name='avatar_add'),
```

The handling view:

```
@login_required
def AddAvatar(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['avatar'] and request.user.profile.slug == slug:
        form_avatar = AvatarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_avatar.is_valid():
            profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
            profile.avatar = form_avatar.cleaned_data['avatar']
            profile.save()   #  <--get err here
            return HttpResponse(form_avatar.cleaned_data['avatar'])
```

While saving profie I get error as above. Another problem is that `def save()` function will be never called, because I'm not saving ModalForm() instance, but just using it to update something other. I'm newbie in Django, please help.

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BA\DjangoProjects\szmatkaPL\core\views.py" in AddAvatar
  209.             profile.save()

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  806.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  836.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  900.                       for f in non_pks]

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in <listcomp>
  900.                       for f in non_pks]

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  296.             file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  93.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in generate_filename
  327.             filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)

    File "C:\Users\BA\DjangoProjects\szmatkaPL\core\misc.py" in get_upload_avatar
  12.     return os.path.join('profile', 'images', 'avatar', instance.profile.user.username, filename)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/xruchawicax/avatar_add
Exception Value: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

Comment: Show the full error and traceback. Where is this occurring? Do you have a custom save method on the model? Why have you defined one on the form since as you say you're never calling it?

Comment: I don't have custom save method on the model, err occures when I try to save profile. I know, I'm never calling it, I just wonder where I have to make thumbnail - in view or in forms.py

Comment: You still need to post the full traceback.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/3TREWDY

Comment: Well that is clearly showing that the error happens in `get_upload_avatar`. Now you need to show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error most probably is in your upload_to function "get_upload_avatar" in the model definition. It should be instance.user not instance.profile.user.

Comment: You're right, I'm a fool, thanks. I'm just copied this function from Image class, that has foreign key profile.